# R: How to split a bimodal distribution in two, and calculate probabilities of samples being in either

Tags: r, split, probability, mixed-models, poisson

I have a bimodal distribution consisting of two poisson distributions as graphed below.

[image]

I would like to divide the bimodal distribution into two poisson distributions, such that I for each sample have the probability of it being in either of the distributions (e.g. sample x has 80 % of coming from distribution D1, and 20 % in distribution D2).

Here I have some sample data.

```
data <- c(16,41,88,0,43,0,0,102,95,28,78,77,28,27,111,97,57,0,55,82,0,24,99,105,47,31,98,20,0,36,34,65,34,24,77,13,85,125,50,46,79,34,23,23,84,43,113,61,29,130,64,0,78,32,72,50,17,69,69,86,0,27,10,62,88,83,0,43,21,0,87,101,21,24,89,0,0,21,0,0,27,136,74,17,125,36,42,100,97,32,17,26,74,0,143,47,61,87,70,34,88,75,36,0,116,36,53,54,0,5,0,0,31,110,93,130,63,35,89,93,0,35,41,78,74,56,68,46,53,19,16,46,132,79,0,54,19,107,0,65,18,5,51,63,117,71,65,80,114,0,73,32,26,0,55,60,78,74,60,25,155,0,45,63,0,87,44,38,81,67,18,111,40,25,27,0,131,90,5,0,113,54,0,84,0,76,47,113,0,89,114,31,42,0,23,67,126,110,109,44)
```

I have tried to use the **mixtools**-package, but I am no sure how to use the output to get probabilities. (note: The probabilities for x being in D1 or D2 should add up to 1).

Comment: I'm not sure I can see the bimodal part you described. Do you know which observations belong to which Poisson distribution? Do you know the underlying lambda parameter for both distributions?

Comment: I dont know the underlying functions. There are two distributions, but I could not post all my data here. If you look at this link, the data has somethink like lamda 1 and 5. https://www.umass.edu/wsp/images/poisson3.gif